# F#: turn old IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() style iterator into a seq

Tags: f#

There are still a few things around in the .NET standard libraries that only expose the old school `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()` iterator to the outside world, which is not very friendly to the F# seq-processing style. I was doing a quick google on how to get the resulting groups of a `Regex.Match(...)` into a list I could process, and didn't find anything.

I had this:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
let input = "args=(hello, world, foo, bar)"
let mtc = Regex.Match( input, "args=\(([\w\s,]+)\)" )
```

What I'd like is to get access to `mtc.Groups` as a seq or as a list, but it doesn't allow this because it's a ye olde `ICollection`, which only exposes a `GetEnumerator()` method. So while you can do

```
mtc.Groups.[1].Value
```

you cannot do

```
mtc.Groups |> Seq.skip 1 // <=== THIS QUESTION IS ABOUT HOW TO ACHIEVE THIS
```

as this results in

```
error FS0001: The type 'Text.RegularExpressions.GroupCollection' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>
```

(For clarity, `GroupCollection` implements `ICollection`, which is a sub-interface of `IEnumerable`.)

So the question is: how do I neatly turn a `GetEnumerator()` into a seq?

Comment: Not unexpectedly, this is indeed a dupe. I'm guessing I didn't find the original because it doesn't mention `GetEnumerator()` once. Other than that, it is exactly the same, agreed.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is really nothing complicated, it's just here for the next person who is googling for a quick answer. The idea is to wrap the horrid imperativeness in a `seq {...}` expression and to then cast the resulting `seq<obj>` to whatever you happen to know the results to be.

```
seq { let i = mtc.Groups.GetEnumerator() in while i.MoveNext() do yield i.Current } 
|> Seq.cast<Text.RegularExpressions.Group> 
|> Seq.map (fun m -> m.Value)
|> List.ofSeq
```

when run on the input described above, this produces the required output:

```
val input : string = "args=(hello, world, foo, bar)"
val mtc : Match = args=(hello, world, foo, bar)
val it : string list = ["args=(hello, world, foo, bar)"; "hello, world, foo, bar"]
```

As I said, I'm putting it here for the next googler of the answer so improvements, suggestions, downvotes, dupe flags all welcome.

EDIT: as per the suggestion in the first comment, `Seq.cast` is clever enough to eat `IEnumerable`s directly. So the seq-expression is simply unnecessary and the answer to this is just `Seq.cast<Text.RegularExpressions.Group>`! Let me know if I should just remove this question.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `seq` expression - `mtc.Groups |> Seq.cast<Group>` should also work.

Comment: Oh yes, so it does. I did not pay attention to the type `Seq.cast` takes. Thanks very much.